# Get value of a protected field

Tags: c#

My method is being passed an object as parameter from third party code.  The class in question is called: `SqlExpression<T>`.

This class has the following protected field:

```cs
protected List<ModelDefinition> tableDefs = new List<ModelDefinition>();
```

I need the info inside that property but I have checked the class and there is no public accessor.

I tried making a child class:

```cs
public class SqlExpressionExtension<T> : SqlExpression<T>
{
    public SqlExpressionExtension(IOrmLiteDialectProvider dialectProvider) : base(dialectProvider)
    {
    }

    public List<Type> GeTableTypes()
    {
        return this.tableDefs.Select(x => x.ModelType).ToList();
    }
}
```

And then casting `SqlExpression<T>` to `SqlExpressionExtension<T>` like so:

```cs
var types = ((SqlExpressionExtension<T>)query).GeTableTypes();
```

But I get an exception that it is unable to cast the type.

What is the right way to get this data?

Comment: Off the top of my head, is it possible to make a static getter method in your child class that takes an instance of the base class and returns the protected field? It feels dirty but I think it might compile and run.

Comment: I think I misunderstand.  If the base class is passed to a method in child class then the property is still not accessible.  Can you show me an example?

Comment: Clever idea, but a derived class cannot access protected members from an instance of the base class. See [CS1540](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1540). You're going to need to use Reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use reflection to get to the field:

Get the type:

```
var queryType = query.GetType();
```

Then get the FieldInfo:

```
var tableDefsField = queryType.GetField("tableDefs", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Finally get the value of the field:

```
var tableDefs = (List<ModelDefinition>)tableDefsField.GetValue(query);
```

However, like any use of reflection in this way, because it is not public, you cannot guarantee this will work in future versions of SqlExpression<T>